# How will I call an azure web app from a html hyperlink?

Tags: python, html, azure, flask, azure-webapps

I have made an azure web app which sends email to outlook.

In the email html body there is one hyperlink and when user clicks on that link, it will call another azure web app. So, right now my requirement is to connect with another azure web app using the hyperlink. The azure web app is written in python flask and I need to call that flask app from the hyperlink.

How to configure that in the hyperlink and call another azure web app ?

Any suggestion will help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any specific reason for opting for Azure Web Apps? If you're looking for process or workflow automation, Azure Logic Apps are the way to go: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview

Comment: the organization where I am currently working in has opted for Azure web app service. Thats why I need to connect with or call the azure web app (written in python flask) from the html hyperlink mentioned in the email body. (its my company mail server)

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT let me know if you have some insight in it. I have edited my question with more clarity. So, please check and let me know.

Comment: Your requirement is still not very clear to me. If your python app is already deployed to an Azure Web App, it would be accessible by the App URL similar to https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net. Will including this in the email directly not suffice?

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT really sorry if, I didnt make it clear. My requirement is that there will be an email body which will contain a hyperlink.  If, user clicks on that link it will call azure web app. So, my question is now that can I make that azure web app accessible by simply providing the App URL similar to "https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net" in the hyperlink ? or i need to configure it in any other way ? I am quite new to azure web app and dont have much knowledge so, thats why i am asking this question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, no issues. Thanks for the response. Yes, your deployed web app should be accessible at the URL: http://<app-name>.azurewebsites.net. Here is a quickstart for your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT thank you on your response.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Summarized the discussion in comments as an answer below.

Comment: Are there any further questions here?

Comment: thank you on your support, i have another query on azure which I posted in a separate question. If, you can look onto then it will be very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62432765/how-will-i-host-a-static-html-page-on-azure-linux-web-app

Comment: Sure, posted an answer there. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the discussion above as an answer:

Unless there is a specific requirement for opting for Azure Web Apps, if you're looking for process or workflow automation, [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) are the way to go.

However, if your python app is already deployed to an Azure Web App, it would be accessible by the App URL similar to `https://<appname>.azurewebsites.net`. Including this in the email directly will suffice.

Here is a quickstart for your reference: [Quickstart: Create a Python app in Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-python?tabs=bash)