# How will I host a static HTML page on Azure linux web app?

Tags: html, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a HTML page which I want to host on Azure web app. I need to host this HTML page in a resource group which is under OS Linux and so I ran the below azure cli command but, it failed.

```
az webapp up -n surveyordemohtmlpage --html -g MyResource-Group --plan MyPlan -l westeurope
```

It was throwing error that ***MyResource-Group cannot be used with the os windows, use different RG***

But, I need to use this particular RG as, I need to connect with other web apps in the same RG which are all hosted in linux OS.

Let me know for any suggestion. How will I change the os to linux in the cli command.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara-MSFT if, you have any insight on this please let me know.

Comment: If it's a simple static website then why not use Azure storage and then host it as a static website? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Comment: no, i cant use Azure storage as, I am going to use in ajax call in the html page and page is cors enabled as well. So, i need to use azure web app service

Comment: @Debartha Mitra CORS is not supported with static website on Azure Storage. Mentioned it in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

az webapp up : Experimental command to create and deploy a web app. Current supports includes Node, Python on Linux & .NET Core, ASP.NET, staticHtml on Windows.

[image]

Hosting static HTML app on Linux is not supported at this time.

Probably you can create it in another RG and configure CORS on the web app.

Comment: Thank you for for your comment. I have currently hosted the HTML page on storage account. Actually, that helps. Right now, I am having issue with CORS.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-up) for az webapp up, current support includes Node, Python, .NET Core and ASP.NET. Node, Python apps are created as Linux apps. .Net Core, ASP.NET, and static HTML apps are created as **Windows apps**.

Also, if you are opting to [host your static website with Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website#viewing-content), please know that CORS is not supported with static website.

Here is a [blog post](https://dev.to/azure/this-is-how-to-easily-deploy-a-static-site-to-azure-31on) consolidating available options.

Comment: thank you for your response, here I used azure storage account to host it. I am calling another flask web app on azure using ajax from the static site and in that web app i have configured the CORS setting and it perfectly worked fine and I can call the web app without any issue.

Comment: Good to hear. Any additional questions here?